# How close must my friends be in order to trade in Pokémon Home?

Tags: pokemon-home

A friend of mine and I recently attempted to do a friend trade in Pokémon Home from remote locations. To our disappointment, we discovered that in order to do a friend trade, you must be within close proximity with each other.

After browsing through the help menu, I found the guidance that covers this and it does state friends must be close by. However, the guidance does not provide any information on the distance that is required. With that said, what required range in order to do friend trades in Pokémon Home?

In Pokémon Go, your friends must be within 100 meters (~328 feet) in order to trade with each other. Does Pokemon Home also have this 100 meter restriction, or is it different?

Comment: Are you both using the same platform or not (switch/phone) just a thought that it may effect it.

Comment: @BobKerman Yes, we were both on be same platform (that being mobile). That wouldn’t have anything to do with it though, because the trading features are only available on the mobile version

Comment: Ah ok, i wasn’t sure if they were available on switch but was considering that it may be platform based